# Sort in desending order

Tags: java

How do I choose integers only and sort them in descending order and put in their position leaving other characters position intact?

I have tried

```
for ( i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i ++ )  
         {
              for ( j = i + 1; j < num.length; j ++ )
              {
                   if( i < j )         //sorting into descending order
                   {
                           temp = num[ i ];   //swapping
                           num[ i ] = num[ j ];
                           num[ j ] = temp; 
                    }           
              }System.out.print(temp+",");
```

I want input as f,2,3,a,9,5 and output as f,9,5,a,3,2

Comment: And we should guess that `num` is a char array?

Comment: What is `num`?  And you realize, *by definition*, `i`<`j` every time, right?

Comment: is there other simple way to do this?

Comment: You're on the right track. You want to compare the values at `i` and `j`, not `i` and `j` directly. Additionally, you need to check if the value at `i` or `j` is a character and skip processing it if so.

Comment: How do i do it? i am new to java.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code you posted is not the one you are trying to run. Otherwise there would be "int i" and "int j" declarations.

Comment: It is not a whole code, just part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the most of your existing approach.
Remove the `if(i < j)` check by a check for digits and swap them if they are digits in the wrong order:

```
    char num [] = { 'f','2','3','a','9','5'};

    System.out.println(num);
    for ( int i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i ++ )  
    {
         for (int j = i + 1; j < num.length; j ++ )
         {
             if(   Character.isDigit(num[i]) 
                && Character.isDigit(num[j])  
                && num[i] < num[j])  {
                 char temp = num[ i ];   //swapping
                 num[ i ] = num[ j ];
                 num[ j ] = temp;
             }
         }           
    }
    System.out.println(num);//Prints f95a32
```

Edit
If you need to work with greater numbers than digits,
you can use an array of String objects instead of an array of chars. And instead of Character.isDigit, you can use Integer.parseInt. Integer.parseInt will throw a NumberFormatException if the string is not an integer, so you have to handle the exception as a no-swap-case.

Comment: But what if i need to add 100,a,.,#,45,4 as input?

Comment: I add a comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way (not the fastest, though) is to pull only the digits out, sort them, and then put them back into the array.

This allows you to use the sorting methods built into Java, which makes it obvious to the reader what you're doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] arr = { 'f', '2', '3', 'a', '9', '5' };

    List<Character> onlyNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(arr[i])) {
            // if this position contains a digit, add it to our list
            onlyNumbers.add(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    // sort using the reverse of the natural ordering
    Collections.sort(onlyNumbers, Collections.reverseOrder());

    for (int i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(arr[i])) {
            // if this position contains a digit,
            // replace it with the highest remaining digit
            arr[i] = onlyNumbers.remove(0);
        }           
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));  // [f, 9, 5, a, 3, 2]
}
```

This solution prioritizes readability over speed. It would be faster to implement a method which sorts the digits in place, but unless you are working on large sets of data, this should be fast enough.